Calculating determinant and adjoint of a matrix of arbitrary dimensions
I am trying to compute the determinant and adjoint/adjugate of a matrix with each entry a polynomial in symbolic variables a[1],...,a[k] and dimension some arbitrary n, so that the determinant and adjoint will be closed form expressions of the a[j]s and n for a matrix with known entries like a square Vandermonde matrix. My thoughts and attempts:

Start from this great SO answer and follow this comment, but I don't know where to go from there, in particular how to substitute matrices keeping the dimension arbitrary/unspecified.
Write new codes, as the determinant and each entry of the adjoint is just a polynomial in the entries of the matrix. Determinant for example can be computed recursively, but again I don't know how to do that keeping the dimension unspecified. The built-in Det[] uses direct cofactor expansion for small matrices and Gaussian elimination for larger ones.

My question: how to compute determinant and adjoint of a matrix with arbitrary dimension?
